# Mocking Dependent Methods in Go Testing

Tags: unit-testing, go

Not sure how exactly we mock in this situation in Golang.

**Situation**: I have an service which has two methods and method2 depends upon the method1. When I was mocking the method2 using the `mockery`, the actual `method1` was getting called. Ideally mock should get called.

Here is the sample I have been working out.

Main.go file

```
func main() {
    s := NewService()
    fmt.Println(s.MethodOne())
}
```

Here is the sample service file which is in the same package.

```
type Service interface {
    MethodOne() string
    MethodTwo() string
}

type ActualService struct{}

func NewService() Service {
    return &ActualService{}
}

func (s *ActualService) MethodOne() string {
    return "MethodOne called"
}

func (s *ActualService) MethodTwo() string {
    return s.MethodOne() + " then MethodTwo called"
}
```

Used below mockery command to generate the mocks under `mocks\service.go`
`mockery --dir . --name Service --output ./mocks --case underscore`

Here is the final `service_test.go` file

```
func TestMethodTwo(t *testing.T) {
    actualService := NewService()
    mockService := &mocks.Service{}
    mockService.On("MethodOne").Return("MockedMethod called ").Once()
    //actual := mockService.MethodTwo()
    actual := actualService.MethodTwo()
    expected := "Mocked MethodOne called then MethodTwo called"
    assert.Equal(t, expected, actual)
}
```

If I run the `service_test.go` actual method is getting called.

```
Error:          Not equal: 
                            expected: "Mocked MethodOne called then MethodTwo called"
                            actual  : "MethodOne called then MethodTwo called"
```

If I were to call other service method instead of the method1, it works perfect (mocked method gets called). But if the method is within the same service, this situation happens.

Am I doing something wrong in the mockery unit tests? Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am trying to run your code, but I get `undeclared name: mockscompilerUndeclaredName`

Comment: Have you generated the mock file using `mockery`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your test, you call `NewService` which returns an instance of `ActualService`, masked behind the `Service` interface (you shouldn't do that most of the time, BTW). You *then* create a `mocks.Service` instance, and call `MethodTwo` on the instance of `ActualService`, somehow expecting that instance to be magically made aware of the mock you've got set up. That's never, ever going to work. If you need to mock something, you have to look at dependencies. I personally like using mockgen for my tests (github.com/golang/mock/mockgen). I'd set this up something like this:

```
package foo

type ActualService struct {
    dep Dependency
}

//go:generate go run github.com/golang/mock/mockgen -destination mocks/deps_mock.go -package mocks your.mod/path/to/pkg/foo Dependency
type Dependency interface {
    MethodOne() string
}

func NewService(d Dependency) *ActualService {
    return &ActualService{
        dep: d,
    }
}

func (a *ActualService) MethodTwo() string {
    return a.dep.MethodOne() + " then method two called"
}
```

With this, you can just run `go generate` to have mockgen generate the mocks for your interface(s), and then write the following test in `foo_test.go`:

```
package foo_test // add _test so you force yourself to only test exposed methods

import (
    "testing"

    "your.mod/path/to/pkg/foo" // import the package you're testing, this test lives in foo_test
    "your.mod/path/to/pkg/foo/mocks" // import the mocks package

    "github.com/golang/mock/gomock"
    "github.com/stretchr/testify/require"
)

func TestMethods(t *testing.T) {
    ctrl := gomock.NewController(t)
    dep := mocks.NewMockDependency(ctrl)
    defer ctrl.Finish()

    svc := foo.NewService(dep) // pass in mock
    // set up the expected number of calls and return value
    dep.EXPECT().MethodOne().Times(1).Return("Mock method one called")
    expect := "Mock method one called then method two called"
    require.Equal(t, expect, svc.MethodTwo()) // check expected return value
}
```

The gomock controller will fail the test if an expected call to a method on a dependency is not made, and because we can control the behaviour of the dependency, we now have control over what data the code we're testing (ie `MethodTwo`) is receiving to work with.

This is how golang's interfaces are best used: interfaces, as a rule of thumb, should be used when specifying function/method arguments. Functions, especially constructors, return types. It's not up to your package to decide what the interface is users of your package need/interact with. Your package exposes an API through the exported names, conversely, your package communicates what it depends on by defining clear interfaces. In this small example above, it's clear that the package `foo` has a constructor, which depends on *any* type that implements a `MethodOne` method that returns a string. In turn, the type returned by this package gives you a type with a function `MethodTwo`, which returns a string. That return value depends on the dependency, which gives you a way to mock it and test the behaviour of `MethodTwo`, where that dependency comes from, and how that is implemented is beyond the scope of what you're testing. It's up to whatever type implements the `Dependency` interface to implement that logic, and to test it.

#### irrelevant side-note

Nowadays, we tend to call everything a mock, but technically what you are looking for here is technically a fake or spy. The differences between a stub, fake, spy, and mock are mostly academic (most ppl will know what you mean), but I'm a bit of a pedant when it comes to this stuff :)

Comment: In fact - speaking of idiomatic Go, I would not suggest using any of the mocking libraries since it is not really necessary to use them. Defining your own mocks is completely fine and reduces the number of dependencies. Good suggestion regarding interfaces, people who usually come from other OOP languages do not completely understand the power of implicit over explicit interfaces

Comment: @OlegI For something as small as this, using something like mockgen is a bit overkill, I agree, but I'm currently working on a large, complex project, so the ability to use `go generate` is reallly nice. This use-case is also one where the OP wants a spy, checking the number of calls to a certain func on a dependency, which you can indeed implement easily yourself, but I thought I'd recommend mockgen, because in my experience, it encourages ppl new to go to write more idiomatic go code.

Comment: thank you for your reply, Elias. I understand what you mean and do agree

Answer (score 0):

You should identify in your code, where polymorphism happens, because where is polymorphism point, then there can be interface, where is interface, then there can be mock struct. But mocking makes dummy empty struct, it doesn't fully implements all methods etc.. its just fakes ur data, so you need to set up properly mockSService.

+

you are not calling anything or not asserting the output of any struct/value which could be constructed with mock service, so this approach doesn't follow up of core meaning of mocking.