# How can I mock a function with no input or output in testify?

Tags: go, testing, testify

I'm currently unit testing a piece of code which uses an interface that contains a method with no input or output. Using testify's mock package, what is the proper way to write a mock implementation of this function?

Currently, I've written it as:

```golang
type A struct {
  mock.Mock
}

func (a *A) DoSomething() {
_ = a.Called(nil)
}
```

Comment: If a function has neither input or output, what are you trying to do to mock it? By the looks of things, the function `DoSomething` is what you're wanting to "mock", while at the same time time, the function itself is calling `a.Called(nil)`, meaning you're looking to mock a function on the same object that you're trying to test for some reason? That seems rather asinine TBH, and this reminds me very much of a related question I answered recently, voting to cllose as a duplicate for that reason.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mocking Dependent Methods in Go Testing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77751591/mocking-dependent-methods-in-go-testing)

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem I'm not looking to mock a method of the object itself. The object uses dependencies through their interfaces. The specific dependency I'm trying to mock has a method which does not require any input arguments or produce any output. I am looking for recommendations on how to properly mock it, not suggesting that the way I've done it is the way to go.

Comment: The answer I linked still holds: using mockgen, you can generate mocks for the dependencies, and check whether or not the dependency is used/called through `usedMock.EXPECT().Called().Times(1)`. If the `Called` method was not invoked, the test will fail. (PS: if you're looking to check how many times something is called, technically you don't use a mock, but a spy - but that's just a pedantic side-node)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say you have something like this:

```
package foo

type Foo struct {}

func New() *Foo {
    return &Foo{}
}

func (f *Foo) Called() {
    fmt.Println("no in/output, does something here")
}

package bar

type Dependency interface {
    Called() // the dependency you want to make sure is called
}

type Svc struct {
    dep Dependency
}

func New(d Dependency) *Svc {
    return &Svc{
        dep: d,
    }
}

func (s *Svc) Something() {
    s.dep.Called()
}
```

Now, using mockgen as outlined in [this related answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77754824/1230836) we can add the following bit:

```
package bar

//go:generate go run github.com/golang/mock/mockgen -destination mocks/deps_mock.go -package mocks your.mod/path/to/pkg/bar Dependency
type Dependency interface {
    Called() // the dependency you want to make sure is called
}

type Svc struct {
    dep Dependency
}

func New(d Dependency) *Svc {
    return &Svc{
        dep: d,
    }
}

func (s *Svc) Something() {
    s.dep.Called()
}
```

This will generate a package under `bar` (as in `bar/mocks`), which contains the generated mock/fake/spy object you'll want to use in your test like this:

```
package bar_test

import (
    "testing"

    "your.mod/path/to/bar"
    "your.mod/path/to/bar/mocks"

    "github.com/golang/mock/gomock"
)

func TestSomething(t *testing.T) {
    ctrl := gomock.NewController(t)
    defer ctrl.Finish() // this is when the expected calls are checked
    dep := mocks.NewMockDependency(ctrl) // create the instance of the mock/spy
    svc := bar.New(dep) // pass in the spy
    dep.EXPECT().Called().Times(1)
    svc.Something() // the test will pass if the call was made

    // alternatively, you can log some output, too:
    dep.EXPECT().Called().Times(1).Do(func() {
        // this gets called as though it was s.Called() in your code
        t.Log("The dependency was called as expected")
    })
    svc.Something()
}
```

mockgen/gomock can do a lot more than just this, read more about it [here](https://github.com/golang/mock). It seems like the repo was recently archived and moved, I suspect [its replacement](https://github.com/uber-go/mock) is pretty much a drop in replacement + some new functionality though.